# Listing of files fails for a directory which begins with a "." ( eg: ".NET")

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to list all the files in a directory. Problem is that it keep on skipping some of the files which are under directory ".NET". Basically it skips any files under a directory name which start with a "." What might be the possible reason?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void addFileToList(list<string>& fileList,const string& directory,const string& excludeFilter,const WIN32_FIND_DATA &FindFileData)
{
    string fileName = string(FindFileData.cFileName);
    string filePath = directory + fileName;

    if (!(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) ) 
    {
        string fileExtension = fileName.substr(fileName.find_last_of(".") + 1);
        if (fileExtension.empty()) 
        {
            fileList.push_back(filePath);
            return;
        } 
        else if ( ( excludeFilter.find(fileExtension) == string::npos ) )
        {
            fileList.push_back(filePath);
        }
    }
}

void GetFileListing(list<string>& fileList, string directory,const string& excludeFilter,bool recursively=true)
{
    string filePath,fileName,fileExtension;
    if (recursively)
    {
        GetFileListing(fileList, directory, excludeFilter,false);
    }

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    directory += "\\";
    string filter = directory + "*";

    // Find the first file in the directory.
    hFind = FindFirstFile(filter.c_str(), &FindFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError!=ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            //cout << "Invalid file handle for filter "<<filter<<". Error is " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Add the first file found to the list
        if (!recursively)
        {
            addFileToList(fileList,directory,excludeFilter,FindFileData);
        }

        // List all the other files in the directory.
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0)
        {
            if (!recursively)
            {
                addFileToList(fileList,directory,excludeFilter,FindFileData);
            }
            else
            {
                // If we found a directory then recurse into it
                if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && FindFileData.cFileName[0]!='.')
                {
                    GetFileListing(fileList, directory + string(FindFileData.cFileName),excludeFilter);
                }
            }
        }

        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        FindClose(hFind);
        if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        {
            //cout << "FindNextFile error. Error is "<< dwError << endl;
        }
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    list<string> fileList;
    list<string>::iterator it;
    string excludeFilter;
    string directory=".";
    GetFileListing(fileList, directory,excludeFilter);

    for( it=fileList.begin(); it!=fileList.end();++it) 
    {
        cout<<(*it)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Updated the code:**

Based on Hans suggestion, I added a check for the directory. Now it works! Any suggestions?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void addFileToList( list<string>& fileList,const string& directory,const string& excludeFilter,const string &fileName )
{
    string filePath = directory + fileName;
    string fileExtension = fileName.substr(fileName.find_last_of(".") + 1);

    if (fileExtension.empty()) 
    {
        fileList.push_back(filePath);
        return;
    } 
    else if ( ( excludeFilter.find(fileExtension) == string::npos ) )
    {
        fileList.push_back(filePath);
    }
}

void GetFileListing(list<string>& fileList, string directory,const string& excludeFilter,bool recursively=true)
{
    // If we are going to recurse over all the subdirectories, first of all
    // get all the files that are in this directory that match the filter

    string filePath,fileName,fileExtension;
    if (recursively)
    {
        GetFileListing(fileList, directory, excludeFilter,false);
    }

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    directory += "\\";
    string filter = directory + "*";

    // Find the first file in the directory.
    hFind = FindFirstFile(filter.c_str(), &FindFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError!=ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            //cout << "Invalid file handle for filter "<<filter<<". Error is " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Add the first file found to the list
        if (!recursively)
        {
            if (!(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )
            {
                string fileName = string(FindFileData.cFileName);
                addFileToList(fileList,directory,excludeFilter,fileName);
            } 
        }

        if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) 
        {
            // List all the other files in the directory.
            while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0)
            {
                if (!recursively)
                {
                    if (!(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )
                    {
                        string fileName = string(FindFileData.cFileName);
                        addFileToList(fileList,directory,excludeFilter,fileName);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        if ( string(FindFileData.cFileName)=="." || string(FindFileData.cFileName)==".." ) continue;
                        GetFileListing(fileList, directory + string(FindFileData.cFileName),excludeFilter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        FindClose(hFind);
        if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        {
            //cout << "FindNextFile error. Error is "<< dwError << endl;
        }
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    list<string> fileList;
    list<string>::iterator it;
    string excludeFilter;
    string directory=".";
    GetFileListing(fileList, directory,excludeFilter);

    for( it=fileList.begin(); it!=fileList.end();++it) 
    {
        cout<<(*it)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not checking if the first found match is a directory, you always assume it is a file.

Comment: There is not even a single working code which gives directory listing which covers all the cases in windows.I just posted this code for the community. Do you really think this is too localized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void addFileToList(list<string>& fileList, const string& directory, const string& fileName, const string& excludeFilter)
{
    string fileExtension = fileName.substr(fileName.find_last_of(".") + 1);
    if (!fileExtension.empty()) 
    {
        if (excludeFilter.find(fileExtension) != string::npos)
            return;
    } 

    fileList.push_back(directory + fileName);
}

void GetFileListing(list<string>& fileList, string directory, const string& excludeFilter, bool recursively = true)
{
    string filePath;

    directory += "\\";
    string filter = directory + "*";

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(filter.c_str(), &FindFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            //cout << "Invalid file handle for filter " << filter << ". Error is " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) 
        {
            if ((recursively) && (lstrcmp(FindFileData.cFileName, TEXT(".")) != 0) && (lstrcmp(FindFileData.cFileName, TEXT("..")) != 0))
                GetFileListing(fileList, directory + FindFileData.cFileName, excludeFilter);
        }
        else
            addFileToList(fileList, directory, FindFileData.cFileName, excludeFilter);
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0);

    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);

    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        //cout << "FindNextFile error. Error is "<< dwError << endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    list<string> fileList;
    GetFileListing(fileList, ".", "");

    for(list<string>::iterator it = fileList.begin(); it != fileList.end(); ++it) 
    {
        cout << (*it) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```